# Why Xsd Cannot Load a Transcoding Service?

Tags: c++, xsd, transcoding, codesynthesis

I am using CodeSynthesis XSD (XML Data Binding Tool for C++) to auto-generate .hpp and .cpp files from a .xsd file. But when running xsd over my .xsd file, I am getting this error:

```
Could not load a transcoding service
```

I am using openSUSE Leap-42.2, Xsd 4.0 and Apache Xercess 3.1.4. Here are the detailed message:

```
Scanning dependencies of target XSDModel
[  2%] Generating C++/XML mapping
Could not load a transcoding service
lib/CMakeFiles/XSDModel.dir/build.make:51: recipe for target 'src/model/Model.cpp' failed
make[2]: *** [src/model/Model.cpp] Error 255
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: recipe for target 'lib/CMakeFiles/XSDModel.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/XSDModel.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
[  2%] Generating C++/XML mapping
Could not load a transcoding service
lib/CMakeFiles/XSDModel.dir/build.make:51: recipe for target 'src/model/Model.cpp' failed
make[2]: *** [src/model/Model.cpp] Error 255
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: recipe for target 'lib/CMakeFiles/XSDModel.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/XSDModel.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Edit 1:**
I've built Apache Xercess with `--enable-transcoder-gnuiconv`switch and `iconv` is installed on my machine as well.

**Edit 2:**
After some digging, I found that the `echo $LANG` command on my linux prints an empty line. In addition, running `localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8`prints this error:

```
character map file `UTF-8' not found: No such file or directory
cannot read character map directory `/usr/share/i18n/charmaps': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No locale has been defined on this linux. So, simply set a locale:

```
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and afterwards, everything will be fine.

Comment: Had same issue on an old centos5 docker image: tested this right now and works perfectly, thanks